# I want to disable bootstrap datetimepicker May, June, July, August, Sept, Oct, November weekends

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker

I want to disable these months weekends 'May, June, July, August, Sept, Oct, November' via bootstrap3 datetimepicker.

Comment: daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6]

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You could use daysOfWeekDisabled setting described [here](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#disabled-days-of-the-week)

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        inline: true,
        format: "dd MM yyyy",
        defaultDate: null,
        daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6]
    })
}).on('dp.change', function (e, selectedDate, $td) {
    //var time = e.date.format("HH:mm:ss");
    //alert(e.date + '  -  ' + time);
    $('.input-field1').val(e.date.format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
    if (check) {
        $('.FormDownDateSelect').slideToggle("fast", function () { });
    }
});
```

Comment: daysOfWeekDisabled this method disables all the months weekends but I want to disable May, June, July, August, Sept, Oct, November weekends only

Comment: @Ammar if you'd like more specific help, please edit your question to include your own attempt to solve this issue. Remember that SO is not here to write code for you, but to help you debug.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan I am not able to make logic for that so that I posted this question but thanks for the comment